# Identify furance/cooling system from wiring?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Is there any way to tell the heating/cool system you have from the wiring? I have a Honeywell th6320wf02 that was correctly working and then I accidentally overwrote its system type. It's wired like this: [image: Wiring Diagram]

It's an apartment so I speculate it's a heat pump and the breaker box has breaks labelled fan coil and condesner.

Comment: `tell the heating/cool system you have from the wiring` ... no, you can tell what kind of system you have by looking at the actual system (brand name, model number, etc.)  ............ you are asking a question similar to this `can you tell the make and model of an automobile by looking at the tires?`

Comment: Can you access the condenser (outdoor unit) for your unit, or the air handler (fan coil) for that matter?

Comment: Are you asking if conventional or heat pump? Yes, usually if the thermostat is wired correctly, you can determine the type between conventional and heat pump. Accordin to what you see in the picture, you have a conventional system, NOT a heat pump.